# vsftp user authentication problems

Tags: users, password, authentication, vsftpd

I configured my ftp user's home dir to `/var/www` and set a password but I cannot login with `ftp 127.0.0.1`, it keep giving me `530 Login incorrect.` Why is this? I'm sure I have typed the password right.

**edit 1**
My config `/etc/vsftpd.conf` looks like:

```
# Example config file /etc/vsftpd.conf
#
# The default compiled in settings are fairly paranoid. This sample file
# loosens things up a bit, to make the ftp daemon more usable.
# Please see vsftpd.conf.5 for all compiled in defaults.
#
# READ THIS: This example file is NOT an exhaustive list of vsftpd options.
# Please read the vsftpd.conf.5 manual page to get a full idea of vsftpd's
# capabilities.
#
#
# Run standalone?  vsftpd can run either from an inetd or as a standalone
# daemon started from an initscript.
listen=YES
#
# Run standalone with IPv6?
# Like the listen parameter, except vsftpd will listen on an IPv6 socket
# instead of an IPv4 one. This parameter and the listen parameter are mutually
# exclusive.
#listen_ipv6=YES
#
# Allow anonymous FTP? (Disabled by default)
anonymous_enable=NO
#
# Uncomment this to allow local users to log in.
local_enable=YES
#
# Uncomment this to enable any form of FTP write command.
write_enable=YES
#
# Default umask for local users is 077. You may wish to change this to 022,
# if your users expect that (022 is used by most other ftpd's)
#local_umask=022
#
# Uncomment this to allow the anonymous FTP user to upload files. This only
# has an effect if the above global write enable is activated. Also, you will
# obviously need to create a directory writable by the FTP user.
#anon_upload_enable=YES
#
# Uncomment this if you want the anonymous FTP user to be able to create
# new directories.
#anon_mkdir_write_enable=YES
#
# Activate directory messages - messages given to remote users when they
# go into a certain directory.
dirmessage_enable=YES
#
# If enabled, vsftpd will display directory listings with the time
# in  your  local  time  zone.  The default is to display GMT. The
# times returned by the MDTM FTP command are also affected by this
# option.
use_localtime=YES
#
# Activate logging of uploads/downloads.
xferlog_enable=YES
#
# Make sure PORT transfer connections originate from port 20 (ftp-data).
connect_from_port_20=YES
#
# If you want, you can arrange for uploaded anonymous files to be owned by
# a different user. Note! Using "root" for uploaded files is not
# recommended!
#chown_uploads=YES
#chown_username=whoever
#
# You may override where the log file goes if you like. The default is shown
# below.
#xferlog_file=/var/log/vsftpd.log
#
# If you want, you can have your log file in standard ftpd xferlog format.
# Note that the default log file location is /var/log/xferlog in this case.
#xferlog_std_format=YES
#
# You may change the default value for timing out an idle session.
#idle_session_timeout=600
#
# You may change the default value for timing out a data connection.
#data_connection_timeout=120
#
# It is recommended that you define on your system a unique user which the
# ftp server can use as a totally isolated and unprivileged user.
#nopriv_user=ftpsecure
#
# Enable this and the server will recognise asynchronous ABOR requests. Not
# recommended for security (the code is non-trivial). Not enabling it,
# however, may confuse older FTP clients.
#async_abor_enable=YES
#
# By default the server will pretend to allow ASCII mode but in fact ignore
# the request. Turn on the below options to have the server actually do ASCII
# mangling on files when in ASCII mode.
# Beware that on some FTP servers, ASCII support allows a denial of service
# attack (DoS) via the command "SIZE /big/file" in ASCII mode. vsftpd
# predicted this attack and has always been safe, reporting the size of the
# raw file.
# ASCII mangling is a horrible feature of the protocol.
#ascii_upload_enable=YES
#ascii_download_enable=YES
#
# You may fully customise the login banner string:
#ftpd_banner=Welcome to blah FTP service.
#
# You may specify a file of disallowed anonymous e-mail addresses. Apparently
# useful for combatting certain DoS attacks.
#deny_email_enable=YES
# (default follows)
#banned_email_file=/etc/vsftpd.banned_emails
#
# You may restrict local users to their home directories.  See the FAQ for
# the possible risks in this before using chroot_local_user or
# chroot_list_enable below.
#chroot_local_user=YES
#
# You may specify an explicit list of local users to chroot() to their home
# directory. If chroot_local_user is YES, then this list becomes a list of
# users to NOT chroot().
# (Warning! chroot'ing can be very dangerous. If using chroot, make sure that
# the user does not have write access to the top level directory within the
# chroot)
chroot_local_user=YES
#chroot_list_enable=YES
# (default follows)
#chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftpd.chroot_list
#
# You may activate the "-R" option to the builtin ls. This is disabled by
# default to avoid remote users being able to cause excessive I/O on large
# sites. However, some broken FTP clients such as "ncftp" and "mirror" assume
# the presence of the "-R" option, so there is a strong case for enabling it.
#ls_recurse_enable=YES
#
# Customization
#
# Some of vsftpd's settings don't fit the filesystem layout by
# default.
#
# This option should be the name of a directory which is empty.  Also, the
# directory should not be writable by the ftp user. This directory is used
# as a secure chroot() jail at times vsftpd does not require filesystem
# access.
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty
#
# This string is the name of the PAM service vsftpd will use.
pam_service_name=vsftpd
#
# This option specifies the location of the RSA certificate to use for SSL
# encrypted connections.
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
# This option specifies the location of the RSA key to use for SSL
# encrypted connections.
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key

allow_writeable_chroot=YES
```

and permissions are set to `777`:

```
reg@regDesktopHome:~$ ls -ld /var/www/
drwxrwxrwx 11 root root 4096 Feb 19 20:42 /var/www/
```

And the log file at `/var/log/vsftp.log` only says:

```
Tue Feb 25 21:19:38 2014 [pid 18250] CONNECT: Client "127.0.0.1"
Tue Feb 25 21:19:46 2014 [pid 18249] [ftp] FAIL LOGIN: Client "127.0.0.1"
```

Oh and syslog-ng doesn't say anything at `/var/log/messages`

Comment: What is the UID of your FTP user? I believe vsftp can only work with user ID numbers that are equal to or greater than 1000.

Comment: Are you sure, you want the "chroot_local_user=YES"? Is the chroot environment set correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To enable all operating system users of the local computer to log in to ftp:

Edit /etc/vsftpd.conf, set the line

```
local_enable=YES
```

then restart ftp with `service vsftpd restart`

Put this here: http://www.linuxintro.org/wiki/Set_up_an_ftp_server

Comment: Thanks but `local_enable` ia already set to `YES`

Comment: please see **edit 1** above. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The permissions on this directory would be the first reason. Does `ftp` have write access to this directory?

```
$ ls -ld /var/www/
drwxr-xr-x. 4 root root 4096 Jan 27 08:38 /var/www/
$ ls -ld /var/www/*
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 4096 Jan 27 08:38 /var/www/cgi-bin
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 4096 Jan 27 08:38 /var/www/html
```

#### Can I ftp with /sbin/nologin?

You should be able to login using the `ftp` account even with the shell set to `/sbin/nologin`.

```
$ getent passwd ftp
ftp:x:14:50:FTP User:/tmp:/sbin/nologin
```

Logging in with the `ftp` account:

```
$ ftp localhost
...
...
530 Please login with USER and PASS.
530 Please login with USER and PASS.
KERBEROS_V4 rejected as an authentication type
Name (localhost:root): ftp 
331 Please specify the password.
Password:
230 Login successful.
Remote system type is UNIX.
Using binary mode to transfer files.
ftp>
```

#### Log files?

Also I'm not sure how you've configured your `vsftp` server but you typically have log files so I'd check in there for any messages as to why you attempts are failing. They're often here: `/var/log/vsftpd/*`. I'd also check the `/var/log/messages` and `/var/log/secure` log files.

```
$ grep log /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf
# You may override where the log file goes if you like. The default is shown
#xferlog_file=/var/log/vsftpd.log
```

My log shows my before/after I get write access to the `/var/www` directory for the user `ftp`.

```
Sat Feb 22 22:01:21 2014 [pid 27138] CONNECT: Client "127.0.0.1"
Sat Feb 22 22:01:33 2014 [pid 27137] [ftp] FAIL LOGIN: Client "127.0.0.1"
Sat Feb 22 22:01:36 2014 [pid 27155] CONNECT: Client "127.0.0.1"
Sat Feb 22 22:01:42 2014 [pid 27154] [ftp] OK LOGIN: Client "127.0.0.1"
```

You'll also see these failures in your `/var/log/messages`.

```
Feb 22 22:01:31 byers vsftpd(pam_unix)[27137]: authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty= ruser= rhost=127.0.0.1  user=ftp
```

Comment: my `/var/www` is set to `drwxrwxrwx` and I don't want to login on the shell but by ftp, I don't need to set a shell then, do i?

Comment: @cerr - sorry I confirmed this and you're correct. You do not need a shell to login in this manner. I've updated my A. Sorry about the confusion.